# How do I turn a Future <List> from Firestore into widgets with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I know I'm successfully fetching the data from the DB because I can print it out in `fetchFavorites()` but I'm not dealing with the List correctly in  `_getFavesState` because my result is:

> type List〈dynamic〉 is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List  〈String〉>'

So how do I actually create widgets from my data? Code:

```
Future<List<String>> fetchFavorites() async {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  final userData = await firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();

  var faves = userData.get("favorites");
  return faves;
}

class GetFaves extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GetFavesState createState() => _GetFavesState();
}

class _GetFavesState extends State<GetFaves> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<List> favoritesList;
    favoritesList = fetchFavorites();

    return Column(children: [
      favoritesList == null
          ? Text('No Favorites')
          : FutureBuilder(
              future: favoritesList,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  print("has data");
                  return Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Text('${snapshot.data[index].title}');
                          }));
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error.toString()}');
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              }),
    ]);
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I don't think it is a straight ahead list of strings. It is some kind of record that looks like a serialized JSON: `{CoverUrl : https://...., Title: some title, cid: something}` So the error makes sense. Not sure how that changes the solution.

Comment: which line the error pointed to?

Comment: Add your firebase reference

Answer (score 2):

A few remarks on your code:

1. You don't need a `StatefulWidget` since the data is managed by your `FutureBuilder`
2. `favoritesList == null` will always be `false` since it's a `Future<List<String>>`
3. In `snapshot.data[index].title`, `snapshot.data[index]` is a String, what is this `title`?
4. You can remove the `Container`, it just has a `child` and is therefore useless.

I think we can simplify a bit:
(I left out the Firestore part since you tell us it works fine. Though, are you sure `userData.get("favorites")` returns a String? If so, cast it to a `String` to match your `Future<List<String>>` signature)

### Full source code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GetFaves(),
    );
  }
}

class GetFaves extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GetFavesState createState() => _GetFavesState();
}

class _GetFavesState extends State<GetFaves> {
  Future<List<String>> _fetchFavorites() async {
    return List.generate(10, (index) => 'Favorite $index');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
      future: _fetchFavorites(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot);
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print(snapshot.data);
          return ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: snapshot.data.map((favorite) => Text(favorite)).toList(),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

---

## Update : Album from JSON Data

Your Albums are retrieved as JSON Data from Firestore: Here is an example:

```json
[
  {'cid': '593312', 'title': 'porttitor', 'coverUrl': 'https://source.unsplash.com/640x480'},
  {'cid': '910654', 'title': 'auctor', 'coverUrl': 'https://source.unsplash.com/640x480'}, 
  {'cid': '276961', 'title': 'nullam', 'coverUrl': 'https://source.unsplash.com/640x480'}, 
  {'cid': '413021', 'title': 'rhoncus', 'coverUrl': 'https://source.unsplash.com/640x480'}, 
  {'cid': '299898', 'title': 'posuere', 'coverUrl': 'https://source.unsplash.com/640x480'}
]
```

[image]

Such data in Dart is usually defined as a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

In this solution, we will use the [freezed package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) (depending on [json_serializable package](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable)) to generate the Domain Class `Album`. The code of this class is generate in `your_file.freezed.dart` for the Immutable Domain Class and `your_file.g.dart` for the from/toJson functionality. To generate these two files, you will need to also install the Dev Dependency [build_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner) and run  the following command at the root of your project:

```
flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Once everything is setup, your `_fetchFavorites()` will become:

```dart
Future<List<Album>> fetchFavorites() async {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final userData = await firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();
  var faves = userData.get("favorites");
  return faves.map((jsonData) => Album.fromJson(jsonData)).toList();
}
```

**Note: This snippet has not been tested**

### Full source code using dummy Data

*Note: the [faker package](https://pub.dev/packages/faker) is used to generate random dummy data.*

```dart
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part '66473551.future.freezed.dart';
part '66473551.future.g.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FavoriteList(),
    );
  }
}

class FavoriteList extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<List<Album>> _fetchFavorites() async {
    return dummyData.map((jsonData) => Album.fromJson(jsonData)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Album>>(
      future: _fetchFavorites(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data
                .map((favorite) => AlbumWidget(album: favorite))
                .toList(),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class AlbumWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Album album;

  const AlbumWidget({
    Key key,
    this.album,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Image.network(album.coverUrl),
      title: Text(album.title),
      subtitle: Text(album.cid),
    );
  }
}

@freezed
abstract class Album with _$Album {
  const factory Album({String cid, String title, String coverUrl}) = _Album;

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AlbumFromJson(json);
}

final faker = new Faker();
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> dummyData = List.generate(
  10,
  (index) => {
    'cid': faker.randomGenerator.integer(999999).toString(),
    'title': faker.lorem.word(),
    'coverUrl': faker.image.image(),
  },
);
```

Comment: Re: the type of the List: Actually, it is *not* a String, it is some kind of structure: ```{coverUrl: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/..., title: Title, cid: g0sXLWfkX3OwkSAem9m1}``` . So, it is a "dynamic" something indeed. What does that mean for my code?

Comment: Okay, I see. Check my proposal. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this

```
class GetFaves extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GetFavesState createState() => _GetFavesState();
}

class _GetFavesState extends State<GetFaves> {
  @override 
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    fetchFavourites();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgetList = [SizedBox(height:50),CircularProgressIndicator()];

    return Column(
         children:widgetList,
      )
  }
  void fetchFavorites() async {
  widgetList = [SizedBox(height:50),CircularProgressIndicator()];
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  final userData = await firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();

  var faves = userData.get("favorites");
  widgetList = [];
  //Build the list of Containers here with a for loop and store it in your variable widgetList. I could not understand what you were building so I left that part for you
setState((){});
}
}
```

What I am basically doing is showing a loading animation in the start and when the documents have been loaded using the function from initState and you have made the widgets, I rebuild the class with a list of new Widgets

Answer (score 0):

What was happening was that I was fetching from the database a List of type `dynamic`, which in this case is some kind of deserialized JSON looking text. When I changed the function signature of my function `fetchFavorites` to this, the `build` method of my calling class started working:

```
Future<List<dynamic>> fetchFavorites() async {
...
}
```

The elements of the returned records are accessed as a 2-dimensional array, so:

```
record[index]["title"]
```

and so on.